# Springboot to BigQuery cheaply

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

So we just got our bill for GCP and it was wwwaaayyyy more than we expected.

What we have is a spring boot app that is running on GKE, but I'm going got be moving it shortly to cloud run. This app connects to a cloud SQL postgress db. I have two copies of this running in Canada and US. We have to store raw user data in different data regions because of legal requirements.

What we want to do is export unidentified data from each region into a single BigQuery instance so we can run analytics and get a start on creating some ML models.

How it was originally set up was we had pub/sub exporting to BigQuery. For simplicity I exported each table to different pub/sub flowing to tables in BigQuery.

These defaulted to have each dataflow instance run 4vCPU, which resulted in a large bill. These 5 dataflow instances made up 2/3rds of our bill.

Are there other things I should be exploring? I'm looking into running batch queries exporting data directly to bigquery. I know that wont scale well, but I need to hit a point where we have enough users to worry about scale.

TIA.

Comment: Do you have the capacity to store your Cloud SQL in 2 region in the US? What is the format of the exported table? What's the transformation performed by Dataflow?

Comment: Dataflow does not data transformation. All deidentification is done in the spring boot app. 

What I'm planning on doing is actually using spring boot's scheduled annotation to run a weekly job to send any new data to bigquery.

Comment: If you can have all your database in the US, I have an easier process for you.

Comment: I can't, we have data residency requirements that Canadian data must be stored in Canada.

Comment: Ok, the solution will be less easier, that's all!

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to your use case.

**Sync Cloud SQL data with BigQuery**

I recommend you to have a look to [BigQuery Cloud SQL federated queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries), that allows you to query Cloud SQL instance directly from BigQuery (only read operation). Then you can imagine an easy synchronization with a simple `INSERT ... SELECT (from Cloud SQL)...`

You can schedule this synchronization with a [BigQuery scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries)

The issue here is your data location, because you have 1 Cloud SQL in canada, and the other in the US, you need to have 2 datasets, one in each region, and perform the same synchronization.

So, if you need to perform query between all the data, whatever their location, you can't do that with BigQuery. You must have all the data in the same geolocation (either in the same region or in the US (all US region) or EU (all europe region) -> thus my question for the US only region)

To move the data from a region to another one with BigQuery, you can use [transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/locations)

**Deidentification**

For the deidentification, you can also use a BigQuery request to hide the PII data from the source (the Cloud SQL federated query or the data already in BigQuery) and save the result in a new table. You can also run a delete operation to remove the plain text PII data in temporary BigQuery table (or use [temporary tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#creating_a_table_only_if_the_table_doesnt_exist))

You can also use scheduled queries for that, or use [Workflow](https://cloud.google.com/workflows) to orchestrate all the operation

---

In summary, for these operation, you can forgive Dataflow and you springboot app, I'm sure you can achieve that with Cloud native component, more efficient and thus less expensive